# XAML customize scrollbar in ListView (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need to customize the scrollbar which is created by Scrollview.horizontalscrollbarvisibility. Currently the scrollbar is very thin not like the standard one. I tried changing the style for scrollview but there are no properties to set the height/width/color.

```
<Grid x:Name="Playlist"
      Visibility="{Binding IsShow}"
      Width="960" >
        <ListView x:Name="listview"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourCollection}"
                  GotFocus="StackPanel_GotFocus"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick"
                  Margin="125,198,125,19">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Height="200"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                Height="200"
                                Width="256">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                                   Height="144"
                                   Width="256"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       Height="56"
                                       Width="256"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with modifying the `ControlTemplate`. Doing this will take a lot of your time. [This](https://invokeit.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/customise-scroll-bar-in-uwp/) might help you.